# Error message when push assets via snapshot to destination org

Tags: api, dashboard

Getting the following error when trying to upload packaged dashboard and corresponding reports to destination org. **Any idea what these relate too..?**

```
Metadata File 'Pipeline_Adds_Removes_Reports' error: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 936182158-3772 (-342482893)
Metadata File 'Pipeline_Adds_Removes_Dashboards' error: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 936182158-3773 (-342482893)
Metadata File 'Pipeline_Adds_Removes_Reports' error: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 936182158-3774 (-342482893)
Metadata File 'Pipeline_Adds_Removes_Dashboards' error: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 936182158-3775 (-342482893)
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error numbers like this are actually *log file numbers*, not an error message that can be cross-referenced in some manual (like 0x80000001 in a Microsoft product, for example). Log a case with technical support and they can help you.

Since we're talking about metadata migration, though, there are some something things you can check:

- Check the folder names for each report and dashboard. They should match existing folders of a compatible type. If not, make sure you *export folders* as well as the dashboards and reports.
- Check the folders you've exported, if any. They should match the same type of folder in the target organization. If not, rename the folders in the target organization.
- Check the names of the objects and fields in the reports. They should match existing objects and fields in the destination organization. If not, make sure you *export custom objects* as well.
- Check the data types of the fields in reports. They should match existing data types *precisely* (e.g. a lookup relationship in the source must also be a lookup in the target, and not a master-detail).

Comment: Thanks @PepeFloyd and sfdcfox. I do have matching users and naming conventions so I'll have to see what support says.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario the best you can do is to create a case with support providing the error you received.

I have seen this type of errors before when a dependency for the dashboard is missing  or the user deploying does not have permission on one of the related components. Make sure that the dashboard/report folder and reports are either included in the change set or exist in the target org and that the user deploying the change set has access to them.